# can connect my laravel instance to rds in aws

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I can not connect my rds to my instance it is a laravel project need to know what i am doing wrong i can not connect my rds

This is my .env file code

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=scanvision.cp5ylt0elhnp.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=scanvision
DB_USERNAME=scanvision
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

This is database.php file code

```
'mysql' => [

    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
 'options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $cert_base . '/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'
    ),
],
```

can any one guide me through this i have searched alot but still i am not able to connect

Comment: r u using local project connect remote database?

Comment: Are there any error messages, if so please provide them. think that would be a great place to start

Comment: https://www.scanvision.net/admin this is the page on which i am getting error and when submitting form here https://www.scanvision.net button not working